# Output XML file | API with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, xml, apache, api, codeigniter

I am developing a API with CodeIgniter Framework.

**Scenario** -

1. My application will call my API with http://myapi.com/controler?parA=valA&parB=valB
2. My controller will _GET the request and process it.
3. Controller will call a view with `$this->load->view('response',$data, true)`.

**My View File** -

Response.php

```
<response>
    <status>
        200
    </status>
    <mode>
        VisaCreditCard
    </mode>
    <options>
        <option name="Transfer" url="http://myapi.com/controller/transfer?id=8230&reason=illness" />
        <option name="Cancel" url="http://myapi.com/controller/cancel?id=3934"/>
        <option name="New Booking" url="http://myapi.com/controller/book_new" />
    </options>
</response>
```

Please note that the tag names are the same as I am using in my application although the values inside are vague. This is because I want you to notice the `<options>` and `<option/>`.

**Problem**

Now the problem is when I call my API, CI would do all its jobs and then give out this view where all i get on screen is

```
200 VisaCreditCard
```

When I check to see the Source Code of the page I get exactly what I want i.e the text that I have in my respons.php file
**Expectation**
I want the source code I got in my output to be on the visible to when I call that url.

---

**Server Information**

- Ubuntu 13.04
- Apache2
- PHP 5
- Codeigniter 2.1.3  (Rewrite PHP Short Tags - FALSE &  .htaccess to omit index.php)

---

Comment: if your problem is resolved. consider accepting best answer.

Answer (score 0):

After almost 7 hours of head-banging search, experiment and sufferings came the light.

---

I did two things and it was solved.

1. Set on header that declared `Content-Type:text/xml`.
2. Omit the third parameter `$this->load->view('response',$data)`.

Now my code is :

```
<?php header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); ?>

<response>
    <status>
        200
    </status>
    <mode>
        VisaCreditCard
    </mode>
    <options>
        <option name="Transfer" url="http://myapi.com/controller/transfer?id=8230&reason=illness" />
        <option name="Cancel" url="http://myapi.com/controller/cancel?id=3934"/>
        <option name="New Booking" url="http://myapi.com/controller/book_new" />
    </options>
</response>
```

And, don't forget to convert the `&` into `&amp;` or you will dive into errors again.

Comment: I linked you a potential duplicate. I guess this will be useful for you if you're using Codeigniter. I found it by using your questions title as search terms.

Comment: @hakre Thanks to notify. I had already removed the <pre> </pre> tags but didn't edit my answer here.